# R- Vectorise table created by %>%

Tags: r

My dataframe `d` is like this:

```
Round    NHA
1        1
1        0
2        1
2        1
2        0
```

I want to create a variable calculating the probability that NHA=1 for each Round. I tried:

```
library(dplyr);
d %>% group_by(Round) %>% summarise(prob = sum(d$NHA)/length(d$NHA))
```

But this function does not vectorize and shows the same result for `prob` for all Round. Really appreciate any help.

Comment: Don't use `d$...` inside dplyr functions. Instead, just call the columns directly.

Answer (score 1):

By using `d$NHA` it is getting all the values in the 'NHA' column, instead we need only the elements that belong to each group of 'Round'.  The syntax would be just `sum(NHA)`.  Also, the `length(d$NHA)` would be the same i.e the nrow of the 'd' data.  So essentially, we will be getting the same values.   If we need to divide by the length of each group, use `n()`, or else use `length(d$NHA)` or `nrow(d))`

```
 d %>%
   group_by(Round) %>% 
   summarise(prob = sum(NHA)/n())
   #or
   #summarise(prob = sum(NHA)/nrow(d))
```